# MYSQL While Loop DropDown

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I have a while loop that display data from table student and an extra column that displays a drop down selection from employee table id which when selected, updates the id in student table. I have the following codes but on displaying it shows only 1 data from the employer table each line.

Here is the while loop. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_result)) && ($row1 =mysql_fetch_array($search_result2))){
echo"<form action=manualallocation.php method=post>";
echo"<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['stud_ID']."</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['stud_NAME']."</td>";
echo "<td>"."<Select name='ex1'>"."<option value='" .$row1['emp_id'] ."'>" .$row1['emp_id'] ."</option>"."</select>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='char' name='emp_location' value='" .$row1['emp_location'] . "'/> </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='char' name='stud_FIELDOFSTUDY' value='" .$row['stud_FIELDOFSTUDY'] . "'/> </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='char' name='student_yearCompleted' value='" .$row['student_yearCompleted'] . "'/> </td>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name=hidden value=" . $row['stud_ID'] . ">";
echo "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='submit' value=update". "></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
```

The query:

```
<?php
    $connect=mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root');
    if(!$connect)
    { die("Can't Connect " . mysql_error()); } 
    mysql_select_db("web",$connect); 
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $updatequery = "UPDATE student SET emp_id=emp_id WHERE emp_ID='$_POST[submit]'"; 
        mysql_query($updatequery,$connect); 
    }; 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM student WHERE emp_id IS NULL"; 
    $search_result=mysql_query($sql,$connect); 
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM employer "; 
    $search_result2=mysql_query($sql2,$connect); 
?>
```

Comment: What's in our queries? Probably... they are different rows number?

Comment: Show your db queries. It seems like you're trying to loop the results in a strange way. Also, I would separate the html from the php code if possible, it will make it more readable and easier to manage in the future.

Comment: <?php
 $connect=mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root');
 
 if(!$connect){
  die("Can't Connect " . mysql_error());
 }
 mysql_select_db("web",$connect);
 
 
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $updatequery = "UPDATE student SET emp_id=emp_id WHERE emp_ID='$_POST[submit]'";
   mysql_query($updatequery,$connect);
 };
   
 
 $sql="SELECT * FROM  student WHERE emp_id IS NULL";
 $search_result=mysql_query($sql,$connect);
 $sql2="SELECT * FROM  employer ";
 $search_result2=mysql_query($sql2,$connect);
  
?>
Thanks for any corrections :P

Comment: There's so many mistakes here. And you're using an ancient, deprecated API.

Comment: If 've 3 lines in the loop it is showing the 1st data in the 1st dropdown and 2nd data in 2nd dropdown and 3rd data in 3rd dropdown. What i want is to display all data in all drop down. 
If i extract the code outside the loop it works well but inside the loop there is something wrong which i can't detect.
Thanks

Comment: @Oliver next time, please add your query to original question. In the comment it is hard to read the code. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to correct the mistakes that i know none please.

Comment: yea i'm going to edit it

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop fails because the two queries returns different rows number. Also, you don't understand the fetch mechanism: on each loop, `$row` and `$row1` values are **one** query row: how do you can build the `<option>` with only one value?

Basically, you have to separate the `while()` loops:

First, fill a variable with the complete `<option>` code for employers (replace field names with your own correct names);

```
$employers = '';
while( ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $search_result2 ) )
{
    $employers .= "<option value=\"{$row['emp_id']}\">{$row['emp_name']}</option>";
}
$employers = "<select>$employers</select>";
```

Then, perform the `while()` loop for the students:

```
while( ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $search_result ) )
{
    (...)
    echo "<td>" . $row['stud_NAME']."</td>";
    echo "<td>$employers</td>";
    (...)
}
```

Generally, you have to figure it how you code can work before writing it.

Also, please note that `UPDATE student SET emp_id=emp_id WHERE emp_ID='$_POST[submit]'` sounds like an unnecessary query: it means that `emp_id` field must be set to their own value.

**The above code is only an example** to help you modifying your code. It is not tested and I don't know if in your code there are other errors. You **absolutely** have to check for errors writing code: follow Jay's suggestion in comments for that.

#### Please note:

> **mysql_** syntax was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and **it was removed** in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the **[MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)** extension should be used.

(from PHP Official site)

Comment: By separating the while loops i can not update a specific line details . e.g  a line consists of student id 113321 and column emp_id when selected in the row will it update the respective student details?